# MySQL - get only record which userids have two specific different values in one column

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

In my log_attendance table there are record of employees, i'd like to get only employees which have mu 3 and 4 on their I(in) and O(out), for example on this table, i will get garcia, arena, imperial and macandil records only, because they have mu 3 and 4.

[image]

```
SELECT 
  Emp_name,
  loc,
  dept_name,
  DATE(CheckTime) AS date,
  TIME(CheckTime) AS time,
  CheckType AS type,
  mu AS device,
  COUNT(*) AS summary 
FROM
  log_attendance 
WHERE DATE(CheckTime) = '2015-05-27' 
  AND loc_id = 1 
  AND mu IN (3, 4)
GROUP BY Userid,
  mu
ORDER BY dept_id, Emp_name,
  mu DESC
```

Comment: ... And when you run your query, what happens?

Comment: the query is the result of my screenshot above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of different query patterns that will return the specified result. Assuming that `Emp_name` is the unique identifier for an employee, and you want to return *all* rows for an employee, if there are at least two rows with that `Emp_name`, and at least one of those rows has `mu` value of `3`, and at least one of the rows has an `mu` value of `4`.

We're ignoring the "date" and "time" columns. We're a little suspicious that there may be some conditions, as yet unstated, on those columns as well.

(If we can understand and accurately describe the specification, the battle is half won.)

There's a couple of approaches.

One of the easiest to understand is to use an `EXISTS` predicate to test for the existence of another row. Here's a way to get a distinct list of `Emp_name` that satisfy the specification.

```
SELECT a.Emp_name 
  FROM log_attendance a
 WHERE a.mu = '3'
   AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                  FROM log_attendance o
                 WHERE o.Emp_name = a.Emp_name
                  AND o.mu = '4'
              )
 GROUP BY a.Emp_name
```

If all we need is the `Emp_name`, we're done. But if we want to return all the rows for those `Emp_name`, we can use that result in a join operation. To do that, we can wrap the query in parens, and use it as an inline view, reference it in the `FROM` clause in place of a table. For example:

```
SELECT d.Emp_name
     , d.loc
     , d.dept_name
     , DATE(d.CheckTime) AS `date`
     , TIME(d.CheckTime) AS `time`
     , d.CheckType       AS `type`
     , d.mu              AS `device`
  FROM ( 
         -- the query from above goes here, between parens
         SELECT a.Emp_name 
           FROM log_attendance a
          WHERE a.mu = '3'
            AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                           FROM log_attendance o
                          WHERE o.Emp_name = a.Emp_name
                            AND o.mu = '4'
                        )
       ) e
  JOIN log_attendance d
    ON d.Emp_name = e.Emp_name
  ORDER BY d.Emp_name, d.CheckTime
```

This will return all the detail rows for the `Emp_name` that meet the specified criteria.

We can't add an aggregate function e.g. `COUNT(*)` to the `SELECT` list without collapsing all the rows into a single row. Before we do that, we need to understand what we're trying to return.

Do we want to return just a count of the rows for each of those `Emp_name`? Or a combined count of all rows for those `Emp_name`? Do we want a count of `mu=3` rows and a count of `mu=4` rows for those `Emp_name`? How we write the query depends on what resultset we want to return.

There are several other approaches to getting the list of `Emp_name` that have both `mu=3` and `mu-4` rows.

We could get all the rows that have `mu=3` or `mu=4`, then group those rows by  `Emp_name`, and the count the distinct values that appear in `mu` for each `Emp_name`, and exclude all rows where that count is not equal to 2. For example:

```
SELECT a.Emp_name
  FROM log_attendance a
 WHERE a.mu IN (3,4)
 GROUP BY a.Emp_name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.mu) = 2
```

(This pattern is also suited for other cases, such as listing `Emp_name` that have at least two out of three possible values of `mu`.)

This query could be used also be used as an inline view, the same as the previous query.

```
SELECT d.Emp_name
     , d.loc
     , ...
  FROM ( SELECT a.Emp_name
           FROM log_attendance a
          WHERE a.mu IN (3,4)
          GROUP BY a.Emp_name
         HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.mu) = 2 
       ) e
  JOIN log_attendance d
    ON d.Emp_name = e.Emp_name
 ORDER BY d.Emp_name, d.CheckTime
```

We could also use a query that has two `EXISTS` predicates to return an equivalent result, for example:

```
SELECT d.Emp_name
     , d.
  FROM log_attendance d
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                  FROM log_attendance a
                 WHERE a.mu = 3
                   AND a.Emp_name = d.Emp_name
              )
   AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                  FROM log_attendance b
                 WHERE b.mu = 3
                   AND b.Emp_name = d.Emp_name
              )
```

We could obtain an equivalent result using two `Emp_name IN (subquery)` predicates, with one subquery returning a list of Emp_name that have `mu=3` rows, and the other subquery returning a list of Emp_name that have `mu=4` rows.

Note that the queries demonstrated here return all rows for the `Emp_name`, not just the mu=3 and mu=4 rows. If that's part of the specification, we can add an appropriate predicate to filter out the rows we don't want to return.

And this is not an exhaustive list, there are couple of other query patterns we could use.

Comment: this is really something great, great answer and great explanation! thank you spencer

Comment: i really learned a lot about your explanation spencer thanks!

Comment: I was reviewing, and I notice that the queries in my answer don't have predicates (conditional tests) on the **`checktime`** or **`loc_id`** columns, which the OP query does. (OP has probably already figured this out, that equivalent predicates will need to be added as part of *every* WHERE clause in the queries above: in the outer query as well as the inline view and EXISTS subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need a `having` clause and to limit the aggregation to the employee:

```
SELECT UserId, Emp_name, DATE(CheckTime) AS date, TIME(CheckTime) AS time,
       COUNT(*) AS summary 
FROM log_attendance 
WHERE DATE(CheckTime) = '2015-05-27'  AND loc_id = 1 AND mu IN (3, 4)
GROUP BY Userid, Emp_Name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT mu) = 2;
```

Comment: i'm sorry but it doesn't show any records if you will see the screen shot above, when i run the query that's the result it shows